# How to fix bootstrap tooltip dynamic content

Tags: bootstrap-4, tooltip

i am using bootstrap4 and loading it like

```
    function fetchTooltips() {
        console.log("fetchTooltips");
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
        $('[data-toggle=tooltip]').on('inserted.bs.tooltip', function () {
            $('.tooltip').css('right', 10);
        });
    }
```

in index file. But title of tooltip does't load latest content which is in bootstrap style 
instead of showing dynamic content it shows another tooltip too which is simple html5 tooltip and its content of title is latest

Answer (score 1):

I just change the "title" to "data-original-title"
and load "myFunc()" placed in index.html header as window.myFunc()

```
myFunc() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
}
```

working fine.